# When creating js widgets, how do I get an instance of my widget?

Tags: javascript, widget

I'm trying to implement widgits the way DevExtreme does it.

When they create a textbox widgit, this is the code:

```
$("#someContainer").dxTextBox({ options... });
```

When they get an instance of the widgit, they do this...

```
$("#someContainer").dxTextBox("instance");
```

This is my widget code so far ...

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.myWidget = function (element, options) {

        var plugin = this;
        var $base = $(element);

        var defaultOptions = {
            id: null,
        };

        var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

        var me = new function () {
            var self = this;

            var init = {

                widgets: function () {
                    // Do some stuff          
                },

            };

            return {
                init: init,
            };

        };

        me.init.widgets();
    };


    $.fn.myWidget = function (options) {

        return this.each(function () {
            if (undefined === $(this).data('myWidget')) {
                var plugin = new $.myWidget(this, options);
                $(this).data('myWidget', plugin);
            }
        });

    };

})(jQuery)
```

With this I can create a widget like this...

```
$("#someContainer").myWidget({ id: 1 });
```

But I would like to be able to get an instance of the widget, so I could do something like this:

```
$("#someContainer").myWidget("instance").showPopup();
```

And also:

```
var w = $("#someContainer").myWidget({ options... }).myWidget("instance");
w.showPopup();
```

How can I get an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to detect the "special call" for when the instance is requested. Here a small example:

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.myWidget = function (element, options) {

        var plugin = this;
        var $base = $(element);

        var defaultOptions = {
            id: null,
        };

        var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

        var me = new function () {
            var self = this;

            var init = {

                widgets: function () {
                    return {
                      hello: function(){
                        alert("it's me!");
                      }
                    }
                },
                
                

            };

            return {
                init: init,
            };

        };

        return me.init.widgets();
    };


    $.fn.myWidget = function (options) {

        if(options === "instance"){
          return $(this).data('myWidget');
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            if (undefined === $(this).data('myWidget')) {
                var plugin = new $.myWidget(this, options);
                $(this).data('myWidget', plugin);
            }
        });

    };

})(jQuery)


$("#someContainer").myWidget({ id: 1 });

$("#someContainer").myWidget("instance").hello()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someContainer"></div>
```